# Bash: Brace expansion precedence and loops over ranges

Tags: bash, shell, operators, operator-precedence

Googled an hour or so for a good, simple explanation to the following. At what point in:

```
for i in $(eval echo "{01..30}"); do
    echo $i
done
```

...does Bash evaluate the '..' component of the brace?

Thanks,

Zack

Comment: `for i in {01..30};do echo $i; done` works too (-:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `set -x` in your shell script to see it yourself ([Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html))

```
set -x
for i in $(eval echo "{01..30}"); do
    echo $i
done
```

And this is the output:

```
++ eval echo '{01..30}'
+++ echo 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
+ for i in '$(eval echo "{01..30}")'
+ echo 1
1
+ for i in '$(eval echo "{01..30}")'
+ echo 2
2
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the `eval` command is presented with two arguments: the string "echo" and the string "{01..30}". The brace expansion occurs when `eval` evaluates the statement formed from those two strings.